# How to pass arguments of my functions to mvrnorm?

Tags: r, arguments

I am doing gaussian mixture model with 2 gaussians. To do it I use "mvrnorm", but I have the following error:

`Error in mvrnorm(r.mixture.gaussian1) :  argument "mu" is missing, with no default`

How can I go about passing my function's arguments to mvrnorm?

Specifically the error I have when I call the function on this line: `X1_distribution=mvrnorm(r.mixture.gaussian1)` and also for `X2_distribution` function.

```
#Define constants
rho = 0.5
n=100
mu11=c(-1,4) 
mu12=c(1,6)
mu21=c(6,1) 
mu22=c(8,3)

#2 functions used in X1_distribution and X2_distribution are defined
r.mixture.gaussian1= function(n, mu, Sigma){
  X = cbind(rep(0, n), rep(0, n))
  for(i in 1:n){
    u = runif(1, min = 0, max = 1)
    if(u < rho){
      X[i,] = mvrnorm(1, mu = mu11, Sigma = Sigma)
    }else{
      X[i,] = mvrnorm(1, mu = mu12, Sigma = Sigma)
    }
  }
}
r.mixture.gaussian2= function(n, mu, Sigma){
  X = cbind(rep(0, n), rep(0, n))
  for(i in 1:n){
    u = runif(1, min = 0, max = 1)
    if(u < rho){
      X[i,] = mvrnorm(1, mu = mu21, Sigma = Sigma)
    }else{
      X[i,] = mvrnorm(1, mu = mu22, Sigma = Sigma)
    }
  }
}

Sigma= matrix(c(1,0.5,0.5,1),ncol=2) 
Sigma <- make.positive.definite(Sigma, tol=1e-3)
set.seed(1234)
X1_distribution=mvrnorm(r.mixture.gaussian1)
mu1=rho*mu11+(1-rho)*mu12

Sigma= matrix(c(1,0.5,0.5,1),ncol=2) 
Sigma <- make.positive.definite(Sigma, tol=1e-3)
set.seed(120)
X2_distribution=mvrnorm(r.mixture.gaussian2)
mu2=rho*mu21+(1-rho)*mu22

X=rbind(X1_distribution,X2_distribution)         
plot(density(X))
```

Comment: 1)You define the mixture functions with an argument `mu` but that argument is not used in the functions' bodies, there you have `mu11`, etc. 2) This doesn't make sense at all: `mvrnorm(r.mixture.gaussian1)`. The call should be `r.mixture.gaussian1(n, mu, Sigma)`.

Answer (score 0):

I did not use the function that I had created, but I used what is inside the function directly, and it works perfect. For example for `X1_distribution`, it was as follows:

```
mu11=c(-6,4) 
mu12=c(-2,6)
Sigma= matrix(c(1,0.5,0.5,1),ncol=2) 
Sigma <- make.positive.definite(Sigma, tol=1e-3)
set.seed(1234+j)
for(k in 1:n){
  u = runif(1, min = 0, max = 1)
  if(u < rho){
    X1_distribution[k,] = mvrnorm(1, mu = mu11, Sigma = Sigma)
  }else{
    X1_distribution[k,] = mvrnorm(1, mu = mu12, Sigma = Sigma)
  }
}
```

And the same for `X2_distribution`.Change the `mu11` and `mu12`and where it says `X1_distribution`, put `X2_distribution`